# Vue3 Laravel useForm from laravel-precognition-vue

Tags: laravel, vuejs3

I am learning vue3 with Laravel and I am looking at a paged lists of businesses that I have attached an "Edit" button to each.

When clicked it opens a Modal with the Laravel useForm Precognition Vue component, however I am having issues with the reactivity of the form.

I have solved it but I would like some advice on my approach because it does not feel right...

```
<script setup>
.
.
import { useForm } from 'laravel-precognition-vue';
.
.
const props = defineProps({   
    business: {
        type: Object,
        default: null
    }
});

let form = useForm('post','/admin/businesses/' + props.business.id, {    
    name: props.business.name,
    address: props.business.address,
    email: props.business.email,
    telephone: props.business.telephone,                
});

</script>

<template>
.
.
<Model :show="state.show" @close="state.show = false">
            <form class="px-2 py-4" @submit.prevent="submit">
                <div>
                    <InputLabel class="font-bold" for="name" value="Name" />
                    <TextInput                        
                        v-model="form.name"
                        type="text"
                        class="mt-1 block w-full"
                        required
                        autofocus
                        @change="form.validate('name')"
                    />
                    <InputError class="mt-2" :message="form.errors.name" />
                </div>
.
.
</template>
```

When used in the above way switching to a new page showed the business object being updated in the props but the form object retained the old values from the previous page and was only initialised once. So If I have 5 items on a page I would get 5 Form objects only. When navigating to the next page I would see the properties updating but the 5 from objects would stay the same, but still referencing the businesses on the first page.

My solution is to add a watcher to reinitialise the form:

```
watch(
    () => props.business,
    () => {
        form = useForm('post','/admin/businesses/' + props.business.id, {
            name: props.business.name,
            address: props.business.address,
            telephone: props.business.telephone,
            email: props.business.email,
        });
    }
)
```

Is that the right way to do this?

Initially I just reinitialized the form properties but the Post target did not change so I did the whole object.

I also can't find any documents on the precognition useForm component that goes into any real details.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you use preserveState: false?